# number of points in dft for convolution?

Tags: signal-processing, fft, convolution, dft

I want to convolve 2 discrete-time signals x and y, both of them having length N, by taking their DFTs, multiplying and then taking the IDFT.

I know that an N-length signal can be represented by its N-point DFT. But since the convolution of 2 signals of length N is a new signal (call it z) of length 2*N-1, does this mean that I will need to take DFTs of 2*N-1 points instead of N?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your DFTs need to be at least 2N-1 points long and that is exactly why.

If one of your signals is much shorter than the other, then it will be more efficient to use the overlap-add technique:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overlap%E2%80%93add_method

https://www.eetimes.com/document.asp?doc_id=1275412